# Is it okay to mix paint thinner with an elastomeric coating for waterproofing?

Tags: waterproofing

Is it Ok to mix paint thinner with an [elastomeric coating (HB-70)](http://web.archive.org/web/20090728050326/http://www.chemisol.com/argushtml/elastomeric.htm) which is being applied for waterproofing?

I have people who have been waterproofing a dome (the right hand dome in the picture below) by applying this coating. However, the coating is apparently very thick, and almost impossible to apply with a brush, so they needed to dilute it. They said that paint thinner was the correct thing to use. I have no idea, so I thought I would ask here. Does such a procedure sound Ok?

[image: Tower Room]

Comment: Contact the manufacturer and ask them. Or look at the container the stuff ships in for usage instructions; I'm sure it will indicate which solvent(s) is/are appropriate (if any).

Comment: @keshlam Thanks for the suggestion.I've written to the manufacturers about this and related matters.

Comment: Questions like that is why paint companies have chemists and chemical engineers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if diluting it too much  will affect performance.  In my case, I use thinner to even the surfaces. I use the tube version  of sealant  , but still application through it is very uneven hence, I wet my fingers with thinner. or you may use , to spread the sealant evenly.